# Can I ask "find me x" questions regarding stock photography with specific rights?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

Such as, "I need a public domain, commercial-use and free-to-modify picture of a middle aged woman with blemishes."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

This is a question and answer site. The goal is to increase knowledge. What you're looking for isn't really an *answer* — it is a specific *thing*. And, it's not *really* a *question* — it's a ***request for someone else to do a search task for you***. That would be appropriate for a [micro jobs](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=micro+jobs+site&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t#q=micro+jobs+) site — not Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, no. That type of question is really going to get shut down pretty quick around here and usually without a moderator doing it.

Answer (score 4):

This site is aimed primarily at *producing* photos and issues related to what is needed to create a specific type of photo such as the one you described. It is not concerned with *finding* such images that have already been taken by someone else. When questions use existing images it is usually to either illustrate the desired result one wishes to learn how to achieve or to show a problem with an image as a means towards discovering what needs to be done to avoid the same mistake in the future.